# Force Switch Default In Java Enum

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

Say I created an enum, for example below:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C;
}
```

And have a switch statement (like below) where each enum value has a case statement, but I also included a default to throw an IllegalArgumentException. (In case a new enum value gets added to make it more likely that someone will notice something going wrong with that case statement if the new value were to get passed. My thinking is Exceptions are much more noticeable than logs or trying to handle the new case.)

```
switch(myEnum) {
    case A:
        //do something
        break;
    case B:
        //do something
        break;
    case C:
        //do something
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognized enum type!");
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, in theory, the default should be unreachable without the addition of a new enum value or altering the switch statement.

So what I was wondering is if I'm writing JUnit tests for code coverage, is there a way to force the switch to hit the default statement without updating application code?

Comment: can you try casting- `(MyEnum)-1;`

Comment: But you could use polymorphism instead of a switch statement to make sure, at compilation time (and not at runtime), that each enum value is covered.

Comment: No, you can't.  Accept that.  (Corollary: 100% code coverage is a myth.)

Comment: @PhilipBrack no, that's not possible. Java enums are not like C/C# enums. They cannot be cast from simple numeric types, because they are not even represented internally as such. They are in fact fully fledged objects.

Comment: @JBNizet interesting, can you expand?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Add an abstract doSomething() method in the enum itself, to force each enum to implement it. Or use the visitor pattern to put the implementation of doSomething out of the enum.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, everyone. @JBNizet I'm happy with the enum itself as I don't particularly want the default to be reachable barring additions of new values. I was just more curious than anything. Thanks again, everyone. Going to answer this since it doesn't look possible barring some really obscure way of finagling it.

Comment: Maybe vote for the JaCoCo proposal: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to force Java to hit a default case in a switch statement as described in the question, i.e. one where all enum values have a case which breaks out of the switch.